# 1c Конвертация документа списание в требование-накладную

Tags: 1с

Хочу сделать конвертацию из розницы в бухгалтерию. А именно в зависимости от значения аналитики хоз. операции создавать вместо списания документ требование-накладная. Я только не давно полез разбираться с 1С, не основная моя работа. Поэтому не могу даже адекватных примеров готовых правил обмена найти. Скиньте, пожалуйста, где можно посмотреть как это делается.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно смотреть в сторону конфигурации "Конвертация данных 2.х" или "Конвертация данных 3.х", в зависимости от того через какой формат происходит обмен данными.

Грубо говоря, просто так взять и сделать без знания технологий обмена не получится.